# How do I style the input of my form in css?

Tags: html, css

how do I style the input of my forms(text)?
I've tried:

```
input type=[text] {
  color: white;
```

}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Please see the [selectors spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview). It’s `input[type=text]`.

Comment: Before posting a question please do some research over the web. This is very basic problem scenario which you can easily find. In the case it is not then your question is probably missing proper insights. If you have not already please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
input[type="text"]
 {
 color: white;
}
```